# running two video an android

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

Can I run two different video player on android simultaneously as we can do on PC.

Assuming I have functions like x² or 2x + 3x² how does one go about creating a SVG path that fits these functions ?.

Comment: Where is the connection to Windows and Eclipse? I added the Android tag. Please create a more appropiate one.

Comment: If you have two or more questions, please create separate questions for each one.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run two different video player on android simultaneously as we can do on PC.

No, at least through Android 3.x. It is possible that `TextureView` with Android 4.0 might support this, though I do not know for certain.

> Assuming I have functions like x² or 2x + 3x² how does one go about creating a SVG path that fits these functions ?.

This has nothing to do with Android, or Windows, or Eclipse.